# Page load on localhost but not in Azure website - Erro 500

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, razor, azure-web-app-service

I made a deploy of a asp.net mvc 4 application to Windows Azure,when I test the application in localhost is everything running ok , but in azure website, have a view that return the error 500 and I don't know why it's happens, could you try to help me here?

This is the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<TestTcc2.Models.Musica>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutMusico.cshtml";
}

<script src="Content/audiojs/audio.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div id="divAudio" class="col-md-4">

    <audio id="audioPlay" src="x" preload="auto" onplay="true" />
    <script>
        audiojs.events.ready(function () {
            var as = audiojs.createAll({
                autoplay: true,
                autoload: "none"
            });

        });

        function replaceAll(str, de, para) {
            var pos = str.indexOf(de);
            while (pos > -1) {
                str = str.replace(de, para);
                pos = str.indexOf(de);
            }
            return (str);
        }

        function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
            var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
            var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
                var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
                if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
                    var rep = replaceAll(sParameterName[1], "%2F", "/");
                    rep = replaceAll(rep, "%20", " ");
                    return rep;
                }
            }
        }
        var x = getUrlParameter('path');
        $('#audioPlay').attr('src', x);
    </script>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
<br />
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <span>Genero</span>
        </th>

        <th>
            <span>Nome</span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span>Artista</span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span>Preço</span>
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    if (item.UserId == Int32.Parse(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString()))
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.genero.Nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NomeArtista)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Preco)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Play", "", new { path = item.path }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.MusicaId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { path = item.path }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.MusicaId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
}

</table>
```

Here is the controller method that calls the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        var musicas = db.Musicas.Include(m => m.genero);
        var _arquivos = modelMusica.listaMusica();
        return View(musicas.ToList());
}
```

I tried to made a debug, but any error is displayed in localhost and in the azure, the following message is displayed:

> Error.An error occurred while processing your request.

In my web.config I set the CustomErrors to off and debug to false, too.

UPDATE ----

Hey guys, I take the DetailedError from Azure:

```
Detailed Error Information:
Module    ManagedPipelineHandler 
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler 
Handler    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler 
Error Code    0x00000000 
Requested URL    http://independentmusicstore:80/Music 
Physical Path    D:\home\site\wwwroot\Music 
Logon Method    Forms 
Logon User    pedro
```

Comment: Set debug=true - also, are you sure you can access the database?  Put the database access in a try-catch clause and use ViewBag to write a message (from the exception) to the view in the catch

Comment: Right. I know that I can access the database, because I can register a User. The viewBag must be displayed at error message, right? Could you put a example?

Answer (score 2):

Do you see an error in the eventlog.xml ? Use the steps mentioned in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/waws/archive/2014/09/24/azure-website-siteextension-to-view-eventlogs.aspx to check event logs or go directly to yourazuresitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/support and then choose you site and choose -> Analyze and then click on Event Viewer...

Unhandled exceptions that bubble up as HTTP 500 should be logged in the event viewer. If you don't see any entries in event log then Enable detailed errors by going to site -> configure in the azure portal and look for detailed errors folder under d:\home\logfiles folder (you can access this via kudu or ftp)

Comment: Thank you @puneet I didn't see this feature, I'll add and post a update here for you

Comment: Hey @PuneetGupta I see this message on the logs: `Exception information:
    Exception type: HttpParseException
    Exception message: The if block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.` But you can see that in the view that I put on the topic, don't have any syntax error...

Comment: Well this shows the error...just make sure you replace the view with a working copy and double check to make sure if the right code is deployed

Comment: Right, but, as you can see at the view that I posted, is everything okay, and the build of VS is passing, and don't show any error.

Comment: Are you seeing the line numbers highlighted in the error message ???

I am thinking that the razor syntax is not interpreting { or } as a server side code which is possibly why you are getting this error. Try setting DEBUG to TRUE in web.config and publish the project in DEBUG configuration (not release) and try running the page again and this time the error message would contain the exact line number where the problem is happening,

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Remote Debugging a Window Azure Web Site with Visual Studio 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/05/remote-debugging-a-window-azure-web-site-with-visual-studio-2013.aspx).

Comment: Hi @viperguynaz, I tried to make a debug, but, when I put the breakpoints the message is displayed in VS2012 `The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document`. I didn't find a solution for this

Comment: Remote debugging requires VS2013.

Comment: Hmm, In this link have a tutorial for visual studio 2012 too, I try, but didn't work. I'll download vs2013

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Navigate to your Website >> Configure Tab:

1. Scroll to Application Diagnostics >> Enable Application Logging (FileSystem only)
2. Scroll to Site Diagnostics >> Enable Web Server Logging (FileSystem), Enable Detailed Error Messages, Enable Failed Request Tracing, Enable Remote Debbuging (if you want to debug with VStudio)

Go back to your website dashboard and click the FTP hostname in quick glance >> Input your credentials >> Check log files

You can also use Kudu console to download logs, view stream, change app settings, etc:

Just type

```
https://<yourwebsitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net
```

- Tools >> Log Stream
- Diagnostic Dump (download logs)
- Debug Console >> CMD or Powershell

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is that you are accessing your database in the controller method. Is the connection string setup correctly in your Azure deployment? If you are deploying the local database test connection string to Azure, it could cause a 500 error.

Comment: Yes, I have the connection string setup in my web.config to localhost and to Azure SQL database. at localhost is everything running, but on the azure environment I can register new users, but is returning error 500 when I'll do a login with a specific type of user